# Chrome Devtools: can I make the whole panel transparent?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I not found any solution for that. Maybe this feature not exist - but I think I may be useful. Maybe I can write some css for Devtools?

UPDATE: I tried to add to the `body` of Devtools `opacity: .5` but looks like it is not a solution:
[image: Chromium Devtools opacity dark theme]

Comment: What panel and why? Please clarify your question as it is currently vary vague.

Comment: @Garbee I mean the whole Devtools panel. Because I want to see bottom part of my page too.

Comment: I think this is because the webpage doesn't extend underneath (so-to-speak) the devtools panel. (You *might* be able to try applying something like `position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0`, but I'm not currently at a computer with Chrome so I can't test it.)

Comment: @gcampbell I tried your css - nothing

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I want this feature too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. The panel is essentially its own viewport space. There is no "page underneath" the DevTools. Think of it like when the DevTools is open, whatever space it takes is not given to the page. This is why it triggers media queries when you resize the DevTools.

Changing the DevTools opacity will only give you a white background, not your page.

Comment: Yep, looks like it is true.

Comment: Mhmm, yes, a total bummer in its entirety. I want opacity with the Google Chrome Devtools window...  :-(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to customise the panels to be transparent using CSS via a Chrome Extension, using the `applyStyleSheet` API call. This is done within a JS file embedded in the referenced `devtools_page` page specified in your manifest file.
See [Extending DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) for more information.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'styles.css');
xhr.send();
chrome.devtools.panels.applyStyleSheet(xhr.responseText);
```

To find the relevant CSS selectors for the panels, you can inspect Developer Tools by opening it in un-docked mode and doing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (Mac) / <kbd>F12</kbd> (Windows) again.

Take a look at [ZeroDarkMatrix Theme for Chrome](https://github.com/mauricecruz/chrome-devtools-zerodarkmatrix-theme) as a full example theme. You will need to enable experimental features in the browser for this to work. As per the link above:

> Open chrome://flags ▶ Enable Developer Tools experiments and click
> "Relaunch Now" at the bottom.
>
> Open developer tools settings ▶
> Experiments ▶ [✔] Allow custom UI themes.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is pretty formatted, I tried to add css - result you can see at screenshot of question :(